# Opening SMS messaging and Address book from HTML (iOS and Android)

Tags: android, html, ios, sms, vcf-vcard

Does anybody figured out how to fill both phone and SMS message in messaging application from HTML page (on Android and iOS)?

If you have this then on some phones it fills only phone but message body is never filled (on other phones nothing is filled, even phone is empty)

<a href="sms:+38615000000?body=hello">Open my SMS message</a>

If you have only phone specified then it works both on Android and iPhone (it fills the phone in messaging app but message is obviously empty)

<a href="sms:+38615000000">Open my SMS message</a>

Is there a similar syntax that works also on Windows Phone because it does not recognize sms:?

Another case...
Is it possible somehow to open Address book from HTML (on some click) and to fill the fields? To copy vCard fields into native address book from HTML?

Answer (score 2):

For iOS > 7, use this scheme:

```
<a href="sms:+12223334444&body=hello%20world%21>Send SMS</a>
```

For iOS < 7, use this scheme:

```
<a href="sms:+12223334444;body=hello%20world%21>Send SMS</a>
```

For Android (though YMMV with the various Android messaging clients, e.g. Hangouts vs. Messenger vs. stock app):

```
<a href="sms:+12223334444?body=hello%20world%21>Send SMS</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As for vCard, i would suggest that your web server serves a vCard file with a vCard mime type, which the phone is likely to understand correctly.

As for messaging, I think there is something coming in this direction in Chrome.

Comment: We had a Save button so we served VCF MimeType but expirienced problem in Android default browser - it always save this file as HTM extension (Andorid 2.2). We don't know why - read about some hack that every user should edit Apache server in their phone and to add this MimeType because Google forgot... When we tried with Opera Mini it worked OK.

Comment: On iPhone we were able to safe file as VCF and when we went to Files folder we could not do anything with it, i.e. to double click and to start AddressBook.

So, the only way we got is to send this as VCF attachment to some email that user provide and from there when he click on attchment it opens AddressBook with filled data.

Thanks fot this info about mobile Chrome - but it is depending on that which user will have this browser...